# P0011: unable to fix

Tags: nissan, cam-timing

Engine: HR12DE
Car: Nissan Micra K13 2011

Hello, I’ve been getting a code P0011 (timing over advanced bank 1) and can’t seem to find the root cause. These are the repairs I’ve performed so far:

- replaced the camshaft and crankshaft position sensors (new ones)
- Changed oil (5w-30)
- Tested the solenoid externally (powered it and heard it function)
- Replaced the timing chain with a brand new one.

At this point I don’t know what else I could do.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the code after you did it. Then start the engine, see if there is a P0011 code warning again.

[**Here is the link to how to deal with P0011 code** : from autoblog.com](https://www.autoblog.com/2016/03/25/p0011-obd-ii-trouble-code-camshaft-position-a-timing-over-adv/)

From that website:
"What repairs can fix the P0011 code?"

- Resetting the fault codes and performing a road test
- Changing the oil and filter to the proper oil viscosity for the engine specifications
- Repairing or replacing the wiring to the camshaft oil control valve for bank 1 intake camshaft
- Replacing the camshaft oil control valve for bank 1 intake camshaft
- Checking the timing chain alignment for jumped timing problems

check the source web I linked above to see the full version.